# How to make a "requireable" lua script

Tags: lua, require

*Hello,*

I was wondering, is there any possible way to make a lua script that contains one (or more) functions that you can "return" them, and require with another lua script?

I tried this, but didn't work

Functions

```
Func = {
function test(a)
 print(a)
end
}
return Func
```

Main Code

```
require(FUNCTIONS_PATH)
```

It gives an error on that point (probably because the code is totally wrong).
I would like some help on that.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate the name from `function`, like this:

```
Func = {
test = function(a)
 print(a)
end
}
return Func
```

Comment: When I try to require, I'm a bit lost, what do I do to actually use the function? I do `Funtions.test()` or something like that?

Comment: @ProgrammingIsLearning When you call `require`, it will return the table that your snippet returned. So assuming that's the variable you saved the return value to, then yes.

Comment: It's saying it can't find the file, as I'm using command prompt, I'm doing `require([[Desktop\Test.lua]])`

Comment: @ProgrammingIsLearning Get rid of the `.lua`

Comment: It is also best practice, depending on your lua version, to make your `Func` a local variable, then the caller can set it to a global or a local as they see fit, as it is now you pollute the global space and the return is redundant.